# How to get a value from Javascript variable and use it on page (post)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm using a third party service that allows you to enter custom html to collect information using a form. There is a the form page, where the user enters information, and the post form page. I asked the service if there is any way that I could spit out information collected from the form page and post it onto the post form page. For example, if the user entered first name John and last name Smith, I want the post form page to say:

Thanks for submitting the form, John Smith.

The service said that it's possible because on the post form page there is a javascript var called fields.

I looked at the javascript they were talked about and found this:

```
<script>
var fields = {"age":"on","city":"San Diego","email":"myemail@gmail.edu","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","officialrules":"on","state":"CA"}; 

.....
```

Does anyone know how I can post this information so that it would spit:

```
<p>Thanks for Thanks for submitting the form, [firstname] [lastname].</p>
```

Resulting in:

```
Thanks for submitting the form, John Smith.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you do retrieve this 'post form page'. Could you give us a link to these providers, so we can see the best way to grab the informations you need?

Comment: You are going to need to study up.  Giving code to a non-programmer is like giving a gun to someone without any safety training.

Comment: I believe that the variable "fields" is set with the values for him with the correct values in them from the post. my answer should work in <that case. @Ori if I'm incorrect and the fields variable is not populated for you then you will need to learn how to put the POST variables into your servers response(the form response page) in a hidden field or something else you can access. Let us know :)

Answer (score 2):

Find your element, firstly adding id to id:

```
<p id="info"></p>
```

In javascript:

```
var p = document.getElementById('info');
```

Add string:

```
p.innerHTML = 'Thanks for Thanks for submitting the form, ' + fields.firstname + ' ' + fields.lastname + '.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following will hopefully suffice to answer your question. However, you should of course also take the extra step of cleaning any data input on the form from a security perspective before trying to render it on the page.

```
<p id="greeting"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var fields = {"age":"on","city":"San Diego","email":"myemail@gmail.edu","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","officialrules":"on","state":"CA"};
    document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for submitting the form, ' +
        fields['firstname'] + ' ' + fields['lastname'] + '.';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to give your `<p>` element and "id" so that you can access it in javascript code. [Here is some doco](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp) on accessing html elements like `<p>` in java script. The element declaration would generally look like:

```
<p id="myId"></p>
```

Next you will have to access the javascript variable and use it in the string you want to store which would look something like this:

```
<script>
    var fields = {"age":"on","city":"San Diego","email":"myemail@gmail.edu","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","officialrules":"on","state":"CA"};
    var myStr = "Thanks for submitting the form " + fields.firstname + " " + fields.lastname;
    document.getElementById("myId").innerHTML = myStr; 
</script>
```

[Here is some doco](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp) for inserting text into the html element that you want it to go into.

[This is a link](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp) to how to access json variables in javascript to do what you're attemping to do.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xq3dJ/) of it working

Answer (score -1):

If you are not familiar with JavaScript and not planning to go deeper, then probably you should use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to simply your work.

```
<p>Thanks for submitting the form,</p>

$("p").append(" " + fields.firstname + " " + fields.lastname + ".");
```

**Demonstration:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/TZAhS/

> This one line of code is all you need. ;)
>   Don't even bother with those complicated "document.getElementById"... pfff just do $("#yourID") in jQuery for the same effect!

This is the most least code you need. Of course you should be giving your `p` an identifier (`id`) so that it knows which one you are talking about.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious, but I don't really see how you could have access to this mysterious 'post form page'. If it's a 3rd party server doing the form processing, how is your code supposed to retrieve this JS object?

Comment: @kuroineko - The process of getting the data object will have to be figured out by himself because he didn't provide any info on it. He only asked how to pull data from it and append it into the DOM and that's what my answer is about.

Comment: @kuroineko - Maybe the data is posted via AJAX and receive the data through JSON(P)? I don't know.

Comment: Well the OP asked how to "post this information", and provided a rather strange sample of a file embedding the POST result inside what looks like HTML. I was just curious about that. A sure way to find out would be to have a link to these providers home page.

Comment: jquery is a javascript library and is never the answer for people who don't know javascript. Always learn javascript first then learn jquery or you will have a lot of problems in the future.

Comment: my understanding is that Ori has access to the html part of the page that the form is being posted to which has a javascript object with the posted variables in it ( at least the non-sensitive ones) he is basically asking how to use that object to populate a html element

Comment: @user1567453 - `Always learn javascript first then learn jquery` I disagree. Although native JavaScript methods are the basis of jQuery and that applies in most cases, if one does not wish to go further into JS, an easier version, in this case, jQuery, will save him more time.

Comment: @kuroineko - He clearly says "Does anyone know how I can post this information so that it would spit *[the fist/last names]* resulting in *[the following sentence]*. By post he doesn't mean `POST` in programming (based on the fact that he knows little about programming.)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 OK, I get it now. My English took a wrong turn here, sorry.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 It's strange you say that because the guys at http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/ would disagree with you XD